# Reproducing Thread Interference

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to reproduce Thread Interference scenario .. but something is not right. Please help me understand what

### Main

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    Counter c = new Counter();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        new T1(c).start();
        new T2(c).start();
    }

    System.out.println(c.value()); // <-- Expect this to sometimes not be 0
}
```

### Counter

```
class Counter {
    private int c   = 0;

    public void increment() { // <-- intentionally not synchronized 
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() { // <-- intentionally not synchronized 
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

### Thread 1

```
public class T1 extends Thread {

    Counter c;

    T1(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void start() {
        c.decrement(); // <-- Decrement
    }
}
```

### Thread 2

```
public class T2 extends Thread {

    Counter c;

    T2(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void start() {
        c.increment();  // <-- Increment
    }
}
```

As i am starting 1000000 threads each of which is operating on non-synchronized section of code, i would expect some operations to overlap.

> Interference happens when two operations, running in different
>   threads, but acting on the same data, interleave. This means that the
>   two operations consist of multiple steps, and the sequences of steps
>   overlap.
>
> It might not seem possible for operations on instances of Counter to
>   interleave, since both operations on c are single, simple statements.
>   However, even simple statements can translate to multiple steps by the
>   virtual machine. We won't examine the specific steps the virtual
>   machine takes — it is enough to know that the single expression c++
>   can be decomposed into three steps:
>
> Retrieve the current value of c. Increment the retrieved value by 1.
>   Store the incremented value back in c.

**What am i missing please?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands your program is not actually doing anything concurrently, everything is being done in the main thread. Since you override the start method and never call the superclass version, then you are not going to get the functionality to get the new thread running.

But just calling super.start() won't fix the problem. Consider start is run by the current thread, so even if you manage to start the thread, the increment/decrement will be executed by the thread calling start(), and there is no concurrent access and modification going on.

I'd move the increment/decrement stuff out of the start method (deleting your overridden version of it) and override the run method, putting it there instead. Of course, consider using Runnable instead of Thread next time, with Runnable it's harder to make this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of problems with your program, beginning by the fact that you do not start any thread. For a thread, the body of the thread must be in the run() method. The start() method in the Thread class must not be overriden.

Then you will have a big problem with the number of threads that you create: 2000000. Which means 2000000 stacks to run them. Default stack size (unless you specify it with -Xss option) is between 512Kb and 2Mb. Even if you use a low stack size of 128Kb, you need 256GB of memory to create these 2000000 threads. Well, you would need that much memory, if your threads were not so short lived. They only do one working instructions then stop, so probably, most of them will terminates before you can start too many of them. Or your process will crash with not enough memory or resources exception. Finally, most of the time will be in initializing and terminating the thread. I estimate less than 1% of the actual CPU used by your threads are used doing the actual incrementing or decrementing of the counter. And that also means that seeing any overlap in your operation is very unlikely.

I think if you really want to see overlap, you want to create much less threads (IMO 16 or less. Any way, only so many can run simultanously, i.e. the number of processor core on your machine), but these threads should do increments/decrements in a loop.

So 2 type of threads, one type making 200000 increment on the counter, the other one making 200000 decrements. Start 8 thread of each type. Wait for the end of all 16 thread using Thread.join() then write the result of your counter.